# Is URL consistency important? Can I have multiple URL styles on one website?

Tags: seo, domains, url, url-parameters

I have a website in which the URL structure is

`mysite.com/Anything_Here/And_Something_Here`.

I would like to have **another section** in the **same site** with

`mysite.com/new-section/and-new-contents-here/`.

Does it make any problems? **Is it advisable**?

Comment: "another section" - an entirely different page of content? And the URL only differs by underscores/hyphens and capitalisation? Or is "anything-here" and "and-something-here" entirely different strings, but differ in "URL format" by the hyphens and all lowercase?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion made, "another section" is different content.

Comment: I have heard someone saying about consistency! Does consistent URL structure provide more SEO juice??

Comment: It's better to have one structure. More can give canonical problems which will result in worse indexation of your content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having different styles of URLs for different parts of your website is not an SEO problem.  As long as your URLs uniquely identify content and are not spammy, they are fine with search engines.

The only place that I could see this becoming an issue is if you tried to apply rules to clean up your URLs.  In that case you might need to write different rules for the different sections of your website rather than apply a single rule site-wide.

Comment: As Sathiya Kumar mentioned in his last comment, Is their a preference given for '-' instead of '_' ?

Comment: Dashes are better than underscores for URLs.  Google treats dashes as word separators but underscores as parts of words.  See: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/dashes-vs-underscores/   That post is old, but Matt recently said that it is still accurate.  Google still works that way.

Comment: Yes thats something i badly needed.. Thank you Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Using more than one URL structure in a website may not create a big issue unless you have 100% duplicate contents on all the pages. But URL structure with 'dashes' is always better than 'underscores'

Matt Cutts stated in his old [post](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/dashes-vs-underscores/) that URL structure with 'dashes' would be more preferable than 'underscores'.

He gave an example for his statement:

> If you have a url like word1_word2, Google will only return that page
>   if the user searches for word1_word2 (which almost never happens). If
>   you have a url like word1-word2, that page can be returned for the
>   searches word1, word2, and even “word1 word2″.

Comment: I too have read about that....but it was really old post i think now a days SE's are more intelligent in that. But i want to really make my new sections have '-' instead of '_' and make it more friendly

Comment: Even though it's old post and though now a days SE's are more intelligent they give more preference to '-' than '_' :)